# How do I redirect after authentication in ServiceStack

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack

I've overridden the CredentialsAuthProvider like so:

```
public override bool TryAuthenticate(IServiceBase authService, string userName, string password)
        {
            //TODO: Auth the user and return if valid login
            return true;
        }

public override void OnAuthenticated(IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session, IOAuthTokens tokens, Dictionary<string, string> authInfo)
        {
            base.OnAuthenticated(authService, session, tokens, authInfo);

            //User has been authenticated

            //Find the user's role form the DB

            if (roleA)
                //GOTO mypage1

            if (roleB)
                //GOTO mypage2
        }
```

I perform a simple post to ~/auth/Credentials and while the authentication works and the OnAuthenticated method is called, how do I actually redirect the user to the appropriate page based on a role or something similar?

I tired to do the following in the OnAuthenticated method but it did not have the desired effect:

> authService.("/views/customers");

**Update using Starter Template (see comment below):**

```
public class CustomCredentialsAuthProvider : CredentialsAuthProvider
    {
        public override bool TryAuthenticate(IServiceBase authService, string userName, string password)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public override void OnAuthenticated(IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session, IOAuthTokens tokens, Dictionary<string, string> authInfo)
        {
            session.ReferrerUrl = "http://www.msn.com";

            base.OnAuthenticated(authService, session, tokens, authInfo);
        }
    }
```

And the form to POST:

```
<form method="POST" action="/auth/credentials">
        <input name="UserName"/>
        <input name="Password" type="password"/>
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The different places where you can set the Url to redirect to during [ServiceStack Authentication](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization), in order of precedence are:

1. The **Continue** QueryString, FormData or Request DTO variable when making the request to `/auth`
2. The `Session.ReferrerUrl` Url
3. The HTTP **Referer** HTTP Header
4. The **CallbackUrl** in the AuthConfig of the current AuthProvider used

Given these order of preferences, if the request didn't have a **Continue** parameter, it should use the `session.ReferrerUrl`, so you could do:

```
if (roleA) session.ReferrerUrl = "http://myPage1Url";
if (roleB) session.ReferrerUrl = "http://myPage2Url";
```

Comment: That worked...sort of...here is the behavior: I have to submit the form twice.

Here is my setup: i have a default.cshtml Content Page in the root where the login form is. Watching fiddler, the only difference i can see is that, the first time i load the page, i don't have a ss-id cookie. Once i submit the form, the server send me back to default.cshtml. But this time with an ss-id. If i submit this second time, the redirection you described works. Whats up with the ss-id?

Comment: One more note, I do get ss-pid and I have Plugins.Add(new SessionFeature()); in AppHost.

Comment: The `ss-id` is described in [ServiceStack's Session Wiki page](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions)

Comment: Ok. Just to make sure i'm not going insane, I installed the Starter ASP.NET WebSite Template - ServiceStact nuget package. Here is the simple form:
https://gist.github.com/4068164
and the auth provider:
https://gist.github.com/4068170

That's it. Run it with the starter template and you'll see you have to post twice before the redirect to msn.com.

Comment: Is the first page you load the HTML form from a ServiceStack page or something else?

Answer (score 2):

mythz,

Good call on making this OSS. :)

You are correct regarding the order of precedence:

1. The Continue QueryString, FormData or Request DTO variable when
   making the request to /auth
2. The Session.ReferrerUrl Url The HTTP
3. Referer HTTP Header
4. The CallbackUrl in the AuthConfig of the current AuthProvider used

So in my example, I didn't have the Continue QueryString, Form Data or Request DTO variable, and I didn't have the CallbackUrl, and certainly not the Session.ReferrerUrl because this is the first post of the Session.

From `AuthService.cs`:

```
var referrerUrl = request.Continue
    ?? session.ReferrerUrl
    ?? this.RequestContext.GetHeader("Referer")
    ?? oAuthConfig.CallbackUrl;
```

By default referrerUrl will have the Referer header value from the request. And that is what is going to be assigned to the Location header further down the `Post` method of the `AuthService.cs`:

```
if (!(response is IHttpResult))
                    {
                        return new HttpResult(response) {
                            Location = referrerUrl
                        };
                    }
```

Once authenticated, and the `session.ReferrerUrl` is set here the response will be sent to the client with the Location property above set to the original referrer, not the value below:

```
public override void OnAuthenticated(IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session, IOAuthTokens tokens, Dictionary<string, string> authInfo)
        {
            session.ReferrerUrl = "http://www.msn.com";
        }
```

It's only on the second POST of the same session will the client navigate to www.msn.com (in this example) because the session has already been populated. I think this:

```
var referrerUrl = request.Continue
                ?? session.ReferrerUrl
                ?? this.RequestContext.GetHeader("Referer")
                ?? oAuthConfig.CallbackUrl;
```

Needs to be determined after the call to auth.

Comment: Agreed, fixed [in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/49833b731d2d8e402be358088ca060cb8bab42f0), available in the next release of ServiceStack at the end of the week. BTW, feel free to send a pull-request for future stuff like this :)

Comment: Awesome. Will do for next time, and btw, great framework. I won't be looking back... I'm sure you've heard this before but SS needs more docs and best practices.

Comment: I think the [ServiceStack wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki) is already quite comprehensive. It's a community wiki so if you feel something could be improved - feel free to add it.